# Referencing Visio Container Nested Relationships

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes

I have a master container shape, which when brought onto the page typically contains further instances of the same container, upto a maximum of 4 levels as shown here.

[Nested Containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsXK3.png)

I then have another shape, which I want to inherit the properties (i.e. the name) of all the containers to which it belongs, and display them in it's own shape data, as highlighted in the above image (with only the last two working).

The problem I think I'm having is that there seems to be no reliable way to reference the nested container relationship in Visio.

CONTAINERSHEETREF() needs either the Z index, or the Z index and a category. This doesn't help here as the Z index isn't the same thing as the nested relationship. If category would work without Z index, I feel like it work work, but it NEEDS the Z index.

I've tried to dynamically set (and guard) the DisplayLevel of the master container shape based on it's type, so something like the following in Shape Layout > DisplayLevel field of the Container's shape sheet:
=IF(STRSAME(Prop.Area_Type,"Site / Campus"),GUARD(-25000),IF(STRSAME(Prop.Area_Type,"Building"),GUARD(-26000),IF(STRSAME(Prop.Area_Type,"Floor"),GUARD(-27000),IF(STRSAME(Prop.Area_Type,"Room"),GUARD(-28000),IF(STRSAME(Prop.Area_Type,"Location in Room"),GUARD(-29000),"")))))

I also tried just simply changing the DisplayLevel to GUARD(-#) in different instances of the container shape.

Doing either of these things, the "send to front" and "send to back" buttons always allow me to click a few levels up or down before it decides it's locked and don't let me go any further.

If I keep clicking them, the Z order will eventually "settle", I won't be able to send forward or back, and the nested relationship will correspond to the Z index as I would need it to in order for CONTAINERSHEETREF it and get the right result. To me it should not allow me to do this, and the Z order should always correspond properly as everything should be in a different DisplayLevel band.

I understand that Z index and DisplayLevel aren't the same thing, but surely if I'm setting everything to different DisplayLevel bands, then everything in a lower band must have a lower Z than anything in a higher band?

Can anybody spot what I'm missing, or am I just thinking about the whole thing in the wrong way, and there IS some way to reference a nested relationships?

Thank you!